# How to align a tooltip at the center of a text selection with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tooltip

I need to align a tooltip at the center of a text selection. That's the code that I have so far to get the correct position:

```
const getTooltipPosition = () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const oRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  const oRect = oRange.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: oRect.top - 20, // line height.
    left: oRect.left + oRect.width * 0.5,
  };
```

this works well if I select a single line or a single word:

[image]
[image]

The problem is when I have multiple lines selected:

[image]

You can see that the tooltip is aligned with the center of the main text container and not with the center of the text selection in the first row.

That's the expected output:

[image]

How can I change this piece of code to reach this result? Not a problem if there's any other approach that doesn't involves my initial solution.